# How do I draw complex objects in Java using the graphics class?

Tags: java, graphics

I have been required by my teacher to draw an object in Java using the graphics class. It could be anything, but that is boring, so I would like to draw something more complex. It is the daedric sword from skyrim, and the picture I am going off of is located [here](http://www.angeltech.info/Creations%20Pages/Resources/atskyrimdaedricsw.png).
Anyway (as we are in the third week of computer science 1), I would like to know to draw arcs and then fill them in with a color, such as the blood red marks on the sword. Her is what I have so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MainPanel extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {                      
Color bloodRed = new Color(187, 10, 30);
g.setColor(bloodRed);
g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
}
}

public class Lab08 extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graphics");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

And please don't say "ask your teacher for help, thats why he's there", because the answer is, I can't. He literally has a sign in his room that says "Google It".

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've already got the entered words, you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] enteredWords = {"here", "there", "everywhere"};
    List<String> randomWords = Arrays.asList(enteredWords);
    Collections.shuffle(randomWords);
    System.out.println(randomWords);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the strings in an array and then randomly access the index of the array.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what an array is, much less how to write one.

Comment: @SomeRandomGuy If you don't know what an array is, then you need to read an introductory book.tutorial about Java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Scanner class to use your custom inputs to be sorted out

```
 Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
 System.out.println("Enter a character");
 String someValue[i]=scan.nextLine(); 
 }
```

Iterate the process using loops and store it in an array until you have given all the inputs and randomize it

```
List<String> characters= Arrays.asList(someValue);
Collections.shuffle(characters);
System.out.println(characters);
```